# Decompose $V(Y^4-X^2,Y^4-X^2Y^2+XY^2-X^3)$ into irreducible components

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Decompose $V(Y^4-X^2,Y^4-X^2Y^2+XY^2-X^3)\subset A^2(C)$ into irreducible components.

I tried like this:

$Y^4-X^2=(Y^2-X)(Y^2+X)$
 and $Y^4-X^2Y^2+XY^2-X^3=(Y+X)(Y-X)(Y^2+X)$. What should I do from here?? Should I take the common factor of both these terms??

Comment: Just use those simple facts (and make sure you understand why they are correct): $V(f,g) = V(f) \cap V(g)$ and $V(fg) = V(f)\cup V(g)$

Comment: This seems to be Fulton's Algebraic Curves 1.25 **