# Question 1.25 of Fulton's algebraic geometry: decomposing $V (Y^4 - X^2,Y^4- X^2Y^2 +XY^2-X^3)$ into irreducibles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, multivariate-polynomial

I have been struggling with [this question 1.25 of Fulton](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759103/decompose-vy4-x2-y4-x2y2xy2-x3-into-irreducible-components) because I cannot find an example of someone doing this explicitly.

> I am asked to decompose: $V (Y^4 - X^2,Y^4- X^2Y^2 +XY^2-X^3)$ into irreducible factors.

We see that:
$$ (Y^2-X)(Y^2+X)=Y^2-XY^2+XY^2-X^2=Y^4-X^2.$$
$$(Y+X)(Y-X)(Y^2+X)=Y^4- X^2Y^2 +XY^2-X^3.$$

We then use the properties from Fulton to simplify the algebraic sets.

$$V (Y^4 - X^2,Y^4- X^2Y^2 +XY^2-X^3)$$ $$=V((Y+X)(Y-X)(Y^2+X), (Y^2-X)(Y^2+X)).$$
We split off the common factor.
$$V( (Y^2+X) ((Y+X)(Y-X), (Y^2-X))= $$ $$V(Y^2+X) \cup V((Y+X)(Y-X), (Y^2-X)) $$
We simplify the last bit.
$$V((Y+X)(Y-X), (Y^2-X))= V((Y+X)(Y-X)) \cap V(Y^2-X) $$ $$= (V(Y+X) \cup V(Y-X)) \cap V(Y^2-X). $$
We use the distributive law of unions and intersections and arrive at:
$$V((Y+X)(Y-X), (Y^2-X))=  $$ $$ (V(Y+X) \cap V(Y^2-X)) \cup (V(Y-X) \cap V(Y^2-X)$$
Which in the end gets us:
$$V(Y^2+X) \cup  (V(Y+X) \cap V(Y^2-X)) \cup (V(Y-X) \cap V(Y^2-X)$$
As a decomposition into irreducible factor.... but this does not look very satisfactory, is this okay?
I have written it as a union of objects, but how do I know these are indeed irreducible?

Comment: You're doing okay so far, but you're not done - what is $V(Y+X)\cap V(Y^2-X)$? (Draw it, if necessary.) As to how you know your $V(I)$s are irreducible, you need to show that $\sqrt{I}$ is a prime ideal, or that $k[V(I)]$ is a domain.

Comment: It's $\{(0,0)\} \cup \{ (1,-1)\}$ I believe.

Comment: Yes, that's right. So what you have written down in the last line of your post isn't a decomposition in to irreducible components yet, is it?

Comment: No that's right, how do I go from the points $(0,0) , (1,-1) , (1,1)$ to the notation $V(I)$ though? Or is it fine to just write a point

Comment: I would get:
$$ V(Y^2+X) \cup \{ (1,-1)\} \cup \{1,1) \}\cup \{0,0) \}=V(Y^2+X) \cup \{ (1,-1)\} \cup \{1,1) \}$$
Since zero is already included in the first curve.